# Footer Missing in website

Tags: footer

Hlo
Suddenly my footer is missing in my website http://www.ubtechszone.com.I am using SpiderMag Theme.Plz help me soon..

Comment: Please share more information. Information like the source code of the footer.php, the actions you took before the footer disappeared, the updates you did, etc. 

Beside the information you gave, this question should be asked to the theme developer.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly give reference about your task/code, what activity you were doing or what file your were editing in your theme. 
In general you should go to your front page template and check `get_footer();` function. If it's not there then call that function.

Comment: the function call is there what to do

Comment: can you share the code of that template ? Also check your theme options if you have turned off footer from there.

Comment: can you tell me wher theme options are located

Comment: This is very basic thing. You can find theme options with in menu of your wordpress dashboard. Further more if you are not familiar with any thing about it check documentation of theme. Or try contacting any developer.
Thanks